# Creating a pdf and cdf for a function - Is what I have done correct?

Tags: probability-distributions, laplace-transform, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have this function:

$$\begin{alignat}{2}%
 & P(0)  = (1 - \alpha) \notag \\
 & P(1) = (1 - \alpha){(e^{\alpha} - 1)}\notag \\
 & P(n) = (1-\alpha) \left( e^{n \alpha} +\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} e^{k \alpha}(-1)^{n-k} \right. \notag\\
 & \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \times  \left. \left[ \frac{(k \alpha)^{n-k}}{(n-k)!} + \frac{(k\alpha)^{n-k-1}}{(n-k-1)!}\right]\ \right)\ n \geq 2\label{md1ssprob0}
\end{alignat}
%\end{fleqn}$$

that I want to create a probability density function (pdf) via the use of Laplace transforms and then derive the cumulative distribution (cdf) from the pdf.

Here is my attempt...

Let $L^n$ be the number of customers in the system and let $S_k$ be the service time of the $k^{th}$ customer.
The random variables $S_k$ are independent and distributed according to
a deterministic distribution with mean $\tau$. The quantity $W$ is the
waiting time for the customer that arrives given $L^n$ customers are in the
queue, that is,
\begin{equation}
\label{wsum}
    W = \sum_{k=1}^{L^n} S_k.
\end{equation}
From the above it follows, by conditioning on $L^n$, that

\begin{eqnarray}
\widetilde{W}(s) & = & E(e^{-s W}) \\ \nonumber
                 & = & \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(x = L_n) E(e^{-s(S_1 + \cdots S_{x})}) \\ \nonumber
             & = & \sum _{x=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{P(x-1)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x-1} P(j)}-\frac{P(x)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x} P(j)}\right) E(e^{-s\ S_1}) \cdots E(e^{-s\ S_x}),
\end{eqnarray}
where
$$
 E(e^{-s S_k}) = e^{-s \tau},
$$
then
\begin{eqnarray}
\label{Ws}
\widetilde{W}(s) = \sum _{x=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{P(x-1)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x-1} P(j)}-\frac{P(x)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x} P(j)}\right) (e^{-s \tau})^x.
\end{eqnarray}

To get the pdf, we need to invert the Laplace transform $\widetilde{W}(s)$

Inverting $\widetilde{W}(s)$, we get
the (pdf)

\begin{align}
\label{wt}
   w(t) & = {\cal{L}}^{-1} \{ \widetilde{W}(s)\}(t)  \\ \nonumber
   & =\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\gamma - i T}^{\gamma + i T} e^{s t} \sum _{x=1}^{\infty } \left( \frac{P(x-1)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x-1} P(j)} 
   -\frac{P(x)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x} P(j)} \right) (e^{-s \tau})^x dt \\ \nonumber
        & = \sum _{x=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{P(x-1)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x-1} P(j)}-\frac{P(x)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x} P(j)}\right) \delta (t-\tau\ x),
\end{align}
that has (cdf)
\begin{eqnarray}
   W(t) & = & \int_0^T \sum _{x=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{P(x-1)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x-1} P(j)}-\frac{P(x)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x} P(j)}\right) \delta (t-\tau\ x) dt \\ \nonumber
        & = & 
       \sum _{x=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{P(x-1)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x-1} P(j)}-\frac{P(x)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x} P(j)}\right) \theta (T-\tau\ x),\ \ t \geq 0, \\ \nonumber
        & = & \sum _{x=1}^{T/\tau} \left(\frac{P(x-1)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x-1} P(j)}-\frac{P(x)}{\sum _{j=0}^{x} P(j)}\right) \\ \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
where $\theta (t-\tau\ x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Is the above correct for the pdf and cdf?

Thanks for your help...